# Changing subdomain url to new root url issue (404)

Tags: redirects, url, subdomain, cname

I have a blog on a subdomain `technotes.tostaky.biz` and I want to move it to a new URL: `www.mytechnotes.biz`. Of course, I want to redirect `technotes.tostaky.biz` to `www.mytechnotes.biz`.

`www.mytechnotes.biz` has been set-up properly, but I am trying to figure what I should do for the redirect.

Right now, I have two A records (`www.technotes` and `technotes`) pointing to the IP address of the root `tostaky.biz` URL server.I also have a permanent redirect (both www and non-www) from `technotes.tostaky.biz` to `http://www.mytechnotes.biz/`.

When I open `technotes.tostaky.biz` in Chrome, I get a 404 "The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

I don't know what is causing this issue. Should I wait for propagation or do I need to modify my configuration? Should I use CNAMEs instead of A records?

**P.S:** I forgot to mention that `www.technotes.tostaky.biz` redirects properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, my (blue) host was not modifying my `.htaccess` properly. I found the solution [here](http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/how-config-url-redirect-whm-cpanel-141985.html).

I used the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^technotes.tostaky.biz/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www.technotes.tostaky.biz/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mytechnotes.biz/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

instead of:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^technotes\.tostaky\.biz$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.technotes\.tostaky\.biz$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mytechnotes\.biz\/" [R=301,L]
```